# Using differentiation for computing $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan(ax)}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence

How can I prove that I can differentiate the integral:

$$ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\arctan(ax)}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx $$

First I have to prove this integral converges.
Next I have to prove the integral $$ \int_{0}^{1} f_{a}'(x, a)\,dx $$ converges uniformly.

Then I can differentiate integral with Leibniz's rule.

I tried Weierstrass and Dirichlet's tests. Nothing succeeded.

Thank you for help in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The given hints contain pretty much everything. $\frac{d}{da}\arctan(ax)=\frac{x}{1+a^2 x^2}$ and 
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{(1+a^2 x^2)\sqrt{1-x^2}} \stackrel{x\mapsto\sin\theta}{=} \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{1+a^2\sin^2\theta}=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{1+a^2\cos^2\theta}\\\stackrel{\theta\mapsto\arctan u}{=}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{du}{(1+a^2)+u^2}=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{1+a^2}} $$
so by the dominated/monotone convergence theorem
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan(ax)}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{a}\frac{dv}{\sqrt{1+v^2}}=\color{blue}{\frac{\pi}{2}\text{arcsinh}(a)}.$$
Differentiation under the integral sign is also known as [Feynman's trick](https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/lg5/Feynman.pdf): it is pretty efficient in dealing with integrals involving $\log$ or $\arctan$ or $\text{arctanh}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for solution. But first of all we need to prove that WE CAN differentiate integral by Leibniz's rule:
$$ I'(a) = \int_{0}^{1} f_{a}'(x, a) dx$$
I talking about the conditions, what I write in start of the post.

Comment: In the first integral, the numerator is $x$.

Comment: @Ilqur: such chance is granted by the dominated convergence theorem. Given $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{du}{(1+a^2)+u^2}=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{1+a^2}}$, you *can* integrate both sides with respect to $a$, *and* switch the integrals $\int(\ldots)\,dx$ and $\int(\ldots)\,da$ in the LHS.

Comment: @GNUSupporter: $$ \frac{d}{da}\frac{\arctan(ax)}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\frac{1}{(1+a^2 x^2)\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Comment: Thanks for explaining.

Comment: @Ilqur: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem. In our case, $$\int_{0}^{a}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(1+v^2)+u^2}\,du\,dv = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{0}^{a}\frac{1}{(1+v^2)+u^2}\,dv\,du$$ also follows from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem

Comment: Thank you @JackD'Aurizio ! 
I understood all of this!