# How to evaluate the following definite integral $\int_0^1\frac{\arctan(ax)}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> $$\int_0^1\frac{\arctan(ax)}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$

My working is as follows;

Let

$$I(a)=\int_0^1\frac{\arctan(ax)}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$

and thus

$$I'(a)=0-0+\int_0^1\frac{x}{(1+a^2x^2)(x\sqrt{1-x^2})}dx$$

(I did this using Leibniz-Newton's formula. I took the partial derivative of the integrand with respect to $a$, and since the two limits of the integral are constants, the first two terms are zero.)

Now, I'm stuck... I've been trying this one for the last hour. Can someone hint me towards the right answer? (which I [looked up](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E1%5Cfrac%7B%5Carctan(ax)%7D%7Bx%5Csqrt%7B1-x%5E2%7D%7Ddx) to be $\frac{\pi}{2}\sinh^{-1}a$)

P.S: I am aware of this site's norm of keeping MathJax out of the titles, but I'm getting a message that a question with this title already exists... Can someone please help?

Comment: See also: [Using differentiation for computing $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan(ax)}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2706052)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now you need to solve

$$I=I'(a)=0-0+\int_0^1\frac{x}{(1+a^2x^2)(x\sqrt{1-x^2})}dx$$
$$I=I'(a)=\int_0^1\frac{1}{(1+a^2x^2)(\sqrt{1-x^2})}dx$$

Substitue $x=\sin\left(u\right)$ thus $\mathrm{d}x=\cos\left(u\right)\,\mathrm{d}u$
$$I={\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{\cos\left(u\right)}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2\left(u\right)}\left(a^2\sin^2\left(u\right)+1\right)}\,\mathrm{d}u$$
$$I={\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{a^2\sin^2\left(u\right)+1}\,\mathrm{d}u$$

Use $$\sin\left(u\right)=\dfrac{\tan\left(u\right)}{\sec\left(u\right)}$$
$$\sec^2\left(u\right)=\tan^2\left(u\right)+1$$
$$I={\displaystyle\int}\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-1}{\sec^2\left(u\right)}}\cdot\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-2}{\dfrac{1}{\left(a^2+1\right)\tan^2\left(u\right)+1}}}\,\mathrm{d}u$$

Substitute $v=\tan\left(u\right)$ and $\mathrm{d}v=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}\,\mathrm{d}w$
$$I={\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{\left(a^2+1\right)v^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}v$$

Substitue $w=\sqrt{a^2+1}v$
$$I=\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-3}{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}}}{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{w^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}w$$

$$I=\dfrac{\arctan\left(w\right)}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}$$

Putting back all the values you get

$$I=\dfrac{\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{a^2+1}x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}+C$$

Answer (score 8):

By Feynman's trick
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan(ax)}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx = \int_{0}^{a}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{(1+b^2 x^2)\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,db = \int_{0}^{a}\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{b^2+1}}\,db = \color{red}{\frac{\pi}{2}\text{arcsinh}(a).}$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I'm not yet aware of the Feynman's trick...

Comment: @AbhigyanC: it is differentiation under the integral sign. Here $\arctan(ax)$ is written as $\int_{0}^{a}\frac{x}{1+b^2 x^2}\,db$, then the integrals with respect to $db$ and $dx$ are switched by invoking Fubini's theorem.

Comment: I studied about Feynman's trick and Fubini's theorem, and I realized that what you've done here is practically the same as using Newton-Leibniz rule and integrating later on... I already did the exact same thing, as I've written in my question...

Comment: I guess my real question is, how to integrate: $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{(1+b^2 x^2)\sqrt{1-x^2}}$. As you've done it in a single step, I'm assuming that there's a single formula to remember that you've used... Can you tell me that?

Comment: @AbhigyanC: the integral $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{1+b^2\sin^2\theta}$ is straightforward to tackle through $\theta\mapsto\arctan u$ and partial fraction decomposition.