# Count an integral with parameter $\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(ax)}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

Tags: integration

Let $a>0$. Count $\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(ax)}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}$.

Can you show me how to prove it correctly that I can integrate the derivative of this function?

Comment: The derivative with respect to what ?

Comment: With respect to a

Comment: [Using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cint_0%5E1%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Carctan(ax)%7D%7Bx%5Csqrt%7B1-x%5E2%7D%7D%24&p=1) you can find some older questions about this integral: [How to evaluate the following definite integral $\int_0^1\frac{\arctan(ax)}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2908585) or [Using differentiation for computing $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan(ax)}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2706052). More tips on searching: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265)